# CSS Connected Bullet Points

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I Usually stick to the back-end when it comes to websites but I am trying to implement a feature for my resume site, I would like the bullet points to be linked via a line. The line is vertical and should break at each bullet point to prevent the line from drawing through the bullet point - it should stop then start again.

I have created a version however there are a few problems; The line does not go through the bullet point, modifying the lines 'left' attribute puts it either side of the bullet point. The line only draws to a fixed size, the ideal line would work on any height by drawing to each li or span

Does anyone know how to allow for the line to draw through a bullet point and for the line size to not be fixed in CSS but fixed on the HTML elements?

If there is already a developed version of this then please re-direct me, I have not found one that meets the requirements.

```css
div#resumeItem {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

/* linked bullets*/

.list-ic a {
  color: #788288;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list-ic li {
  position: relative;
}

.list-ic li span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border-color: #18bc9c;
  border-width: 0.6em;
  border-style: double;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.list-ic li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #18bc9c;
  z-index: -1;
}

.list-ic.vertical {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-ic.vertical li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.list-ic.vertical li span {}

.list-ic.vertical li::before {
  top: -12.0em;
  left: 1.1em;
  width: 0.2em;
  height: 24em;
}

.list-ic li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.list-ic .active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.list-ic .active~li {
  background: lightblue;
}

.list-ic .active~li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}

/* end */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
    <h5 id="profile">Work Experience</h5>
    <hr id="profile">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="profile">
      <!-- Council -->
      <ul class="list-ic vertical">
        <li><span></span></li>
        <div id="resumeItem">
          <h5 id="resume">Test & Test Test</h5>
          <h6 id="resume">Test Test Test - Internship</h6>
          <p id="resume">Test 2018 - Test 2018 (4 Test)</p>
          <p id="resume">Test, Test</p>
          <p id="resume">Reorder elements in a list or grid using the mouse. Examples. Default functionality · Connect lists · Display as grid · Drop placeholder · Handle empty lists · Include ... Click on and drag an element to a new spot within the list, and the other
            items ....</p>
        </div>

        <li><span></span></li>
        <div id="resumeItem">
          <h5 id="resume">Test & Test Council</h5>
          <h6 id="resume">Test Transport Test - Test</h6>
          <p id="resume">Test 2018 - Test Test (Test Test)</p>
          <p id="resume">Test, Test</p>
          <p id="resume">Reorder elements in a list or grid using the mouse. Examples. Default functionality · Connect lists · Display as grid · Drop placeholder · Handle empty lists · Include ... Click on and drag an element to a new spot within the list, and the other
            items ...</p>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Council End -->
  </div>
```

Comment: You can follow these tutorials, they might help you out: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp you're on the right track though, and there are multiple ways to achieve this

Comment: https://freefrontend.com/css-timelines/
https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/FdkEf

Answer (score 0):

You can use border to draw the line and absolute position to adjust to your bullet. To visualize it, I just created a pen using border left to draw a vertical line and border bottom to draw a short horizontal line.

In your case, I would suggest that you set your list-style-type to none, add your bullet in li:before and add padding in your ul

```
// using before to create the bullet
li:before
    display: block
    position: absolute
    left: 0 //position your bullet
    height: 24px
    width: 8px
    content: "" //add something here for your bullet, you can get from maybe fontawesome ot unicode shape
// then use after to create the line
li:after
    display: block
    position: absolute
    content: "" //leave this blank
    top: //adjust the position, e.g 4px
    left: //adjust the position, e.g 4px
    bottom: //adjust the position, e.g 2px, only if it is needed
    border-left: 2px solid #ff5800 //line color
// might as well create padding for ul
ul
    padding-left: 16px

// sample of code in a slight different case to show how the line can be drawn
https://codepen.io/irwanphan/pen/REpQPO
```

I am using SASS to visualize the code, if it is written in CSS, you can add { } to each element and ; to each attribute line.

hope it helps
thanks